# Deployed SSIS package on Sql server exuted by Web api

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, ssis

When execute package then it gives

> error run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install >Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher and Microsoft JET >Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Spreadsheet is full

```
 case "sql":

                    app = new Application();

                    packagePath = "/DESKTOP-Q9Q19T0_SQLSERVER2016/DTS Packages/" + packageName;

                    bool status= app.ExistsOnSqlServer(packagePath, @"DESKTOP-Q9Q19T0\SQLSERVER2016", "sa", "admin@123");

                    if (app.ExistsOnSqlServer(packagePath, @"DESKTOP-Q9Q19T0\SQLSERVER2016", "sa", "admin@123"))
                    {

                        myPackage = app.LoadFromSqlServer(packagePath, @"DESKTOP-Q9Q19T0\SQLSERVER2016", String.Empty, String.Empty, null);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("Invalid package name or location: " + packagePath);
                    }
                    break;



            Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult resultSatatus = myPackage.Execute();

            if (resultSatatus == Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure)
            {
                foreach (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsError local_DtsError in myPackage.Errors)
                {
                    string error = local_DtsError.Description.ToString();
                    err = err + error;
                }
              return Convert.ToString(resultSatatus);
            }
            else 
            {
                return Convert.ToString(resultSatatus);
            }
```

Comment: You need to give more details here. What is the SSIS package doing? Have you done what the error message tells you to do? What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.